# Geocoder request.location returns nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I am using Geocoder gem to find current location. It was working fine before but now when i checked it returns `nil` for `request.location`.

```rb
request.location => nil
```

Comment: Can you show the request you have made? So we can see if it is reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

This will happen on less common searches (ip lookups, some residential addresses, etc.) when the `timeout` is set too low.

You can test this by running a Rails console and manually doing a search:

```
[7] pry(main)> location = Geocoder.search("4.2.2.2")
Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit).
=> []
```

Set your timeout higher in the Geocoder initializer:

```
# config/initializers/geocoder.rb
Geocoder.configure(
  ...
  # geocoding service request timeout, in seconds (default 3):
  timeout: 10,
  ...
)
```

You might need to use 20 or 30. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

From geocoder gem [readme](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geocoding-http-requests),

> `request.location` will usually return **nil** in **test** and
>   **development** environments because things like `localhost` and `0.0.0.0` are not geocodable IP addresses.

Try [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) to expose your local server to the internet.

Comment: development environment, but using cloudflared I get a valid `request.remote_ip` and `request.location`

Comment: oops the important part is **usually**